# Do I use a loop, df.melt or df.explode to achieve a flattened dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reshape

Can anyone help with some code that will achieve the following transformation? I have tried variations of `df.melt`, `df.explode`, and also a looping statement but only get error statements.  I think it might need nesting but don't have the experience to do so.

```
index  A   B   C  D
0      X   d   4  2
1      Y   b   5  2
```

Where column `D` represents frequency of column `C`.

desired output is:

```
index  A   B   C  
0      X   d   4  
1      X   d   4
2      Y   b   5
3      Y   b   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat rows, why not use [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#pandas.Index.repeat)?

```
import pandas as pd

#recreate the sample dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["X","Y"],"B":["d","b"],"C":[4,5],"D":[3,2]}, columns=list("ABCD"))

df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df["D"])).drop("D", 1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Sample output

```
   A  B  C
0  X  d  4
1  X  d  4
2  X  d  4
3  Y  b  5
4  Y  b  5
```

Comment: This has done the job.  Thank you very much for your help.